# Is Windmill going to be fine without a gun?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

At the start of the Alice Garden pod raid, Arie van Bruggen asks you for a gun to defend himself. Since I only had my 3 tricked-out weapons of choice at the time, I declined.

In response, he bid me a merry "**** you" and climbed into his pod, so I defended it by killing everyone in the room.

Is he plot-dead anyway? If so, what *not* unique rewards am I missing?

Comment: @Brant His words, not mine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possible spoilers:

> I gave him a machine pistol and he ran off and later in the game he gave me 2000 credits as a "Thank You"

So at most I think that's all you're missing. Personally I had over 30,000 credits by this point and it didn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine said Windmill died, when didn't give him a weapon.

I did the following:

Instead of giving him a trciked out weapon, reload your quicksave and then go down and buy a gun from a merchant. The one in Alice Pod Gardens has a Combat Rifle as the cheapest weapon (1250 credits vs the 2000 you get from doing it), but that ofc requires you don't have a Combat Rifle already, otherwise dump it and buy it and pick up your tricked out combat file when the combat starts.

Comment: Or just grab a non-upgraded weapon from the pods. There is at least an SMG around.

Comment: Pod 544 has a 10mm that works fine.

Comment: The arms dealer in Alice Garden Pods also sells a revolver, which is cheaper than the combat rifle and still works.

Answer (score 0):

Give a weapon to him; if you do not, he will climb in his pod and hide. Either way he will survive. You will get a monetary reward if you give a weapon to him.